# Storing registration data in database using laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

Have been trying to create a user registration/login page following laracast video.

But when I try to register a user, it return to the same page without given any error as to why. I also noticed that the supplied info is not stored in the database.

Am so confused I don't know what am doing wrong you help will be really appreciated

Here is my view:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-8">
    <h1 class="text-center ">Register</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="register"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required>
         </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" email="email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password_confirmation">Password Confirmation</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i>Register</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my controller

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('registration.create');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       //validate form
         $this->validate(request(),[

            'name' => 'required',

            'email' => 'required|email',

            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ]);

         //create and save user

        $user = new User; //create new Post model object
        $user->name = $request->name; //adding thing to the the Post object
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = $request->password;
       //save user
        $user->save(); //to save the new item into the DB
        //$user = User::create(request(['name', 'email', 'password']));

        //sign them in
        auth()->login($user);

         //redirect to the admin
    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

While this is my route file:

```
Route::get('register', 'RegistrationController@create');
Route::post('register', 'RegistrationController@store');
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Possibly it is not passing the validation rules. Most likely this place `'password' => 'required|confirmed',` can  you try to check if your validation fails? `if($validate->fails()) //Show error`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first you add this error block. so, you can find error easily.

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Then, your mistake is in form action. please replace it to below code.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your form, there's an error in the email field. It says:

and should be:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required>
```

So, replace **email**="email" with **name**="email"

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you so much for your help.